# Need caption when preview the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- When click on image -->

                <div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;">
                                <figcaption class="img-title"> </figcaption>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 7px;">
                        <div class="photo-gallary-head panel-heading ">
                            <h4 title="Photo Gallery" class="photo-gallary-head-name"> <a href="#" title="Photo Gallery">Photo Gallery</a> </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="img-t humbnail">
                                <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel1" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <!--/item-->
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <div class="row">

                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-1.jpg">
                                                        <figcaption class="img-title">A caption for the above image.</figcaption></a>
                                                    

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-2.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-3.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-4.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item ">

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-5.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-6.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-7.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-8.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item ">

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-9.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-10.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-11.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-12.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--/item-->
                                        <div class="item ">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-13.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-14.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-15.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-16.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item ">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-17.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-18.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-19.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <a href="#x" class="pop"><img class="img-responsive" alt="Image" src="~/Images/PhotoGallery/pg-20.jpg"></a>
                                                </div>


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--/item-->


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="carouselButtons" style="text-align:center; margin-top:20px">
                                    <a class="left1 carousel-control1" href="#myCarousel1
                                       " data-slide="prev" title="Previous"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                    <button id="pauseButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" title="Play">
                                        <i class="fa fa-play-circle" style="font-size:20px"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button id="playButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" title="Pause">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pause-circle" style="font-size:20px"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="right1 carousel-control1" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next" title="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have done preview the image with the help of model popup, but need show same image caption when click on image. In this code this is the thumbnail slider with image preview. Here some of the missing file, it is not working. I don't want to show by title but show by caption. This is the thumbnail slider.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: When you get a moment, I suggest you read the [ask] and the [help] pages. A number of your posts are too broad, unclear, deliberate duplicates, or otherwise off-topic. It really is worthwhile understanding what can be posted here, since too many closed or downvoted questions will result in an automatic question ban.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `title` or `alt` tag into image, i think it will take automatically as caption.

Or can you give me your slider jquery url